# Attempting to free() a linked list node causes segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

My question is simple I think. And yes, I am aware that there are several linked list/segmentation fault related questions on stack overflow, but I think those have to do with uninitialized pointers, whereas I think my issue is related to strings.

I have a linked list whose node structures consist of two variables: a link to the `next` node and (!) a `string`.

**my question:** how do I free the memory of the node (keeping in mind it was `malloc`ated) without causing a segmentation fault by `free()`ing the string?

While browsing the other questions related to `free()` and `strings`, I have come under the impression that it is not necessary to `free()` them. But how does one free a `struct` that has a `string` nested string inside it?

The linked list functions I am implementing seem to be working except `destroyList()`, which frees all allocated memory of the node passed to the function along with all subsequent nodes.

Here is the implemenation:

```
void destroyList(struct listNode *pNode){
    if(pNode->next != null){
        destroyList(pNode->next);
    }
    free(pNode);
}
```

and here is the `listNode` structure:

```
struct listNode{
    char addr[MAX_ADDR_LENGTH];
    struct listNode *next;
};
```

Comment: is it possible that you write more characters than MAX_ADDR_LENGTH into a node at some point? might be wrong, but that might mess up your pointer. also, do you initialize next to null upon creation? also see calloc in that respect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "string" (the `char` buffer) is part of the list node struct. It doesn't get allocated separately from the nodes, so it doesn't need to be freed. Freeing the node is all you need to do.

Comment: ok thanks! That means that the problem must be somewhere else in my code. The error message I received was simply `Segmentation Fault' so I am trying to narrow down the possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb is use free() when you used malloc(). Strings do not need to be free()'d as free()'ing the node deallocates the memory allocated to whole structure which includes the memory for the string. And, why dont you use gdb or valgrind to debug where exactly the fault arises? In gdb, you can use options like where and print stacktrace to precisely locate where the segfault is occuring. It's a good investment to learn gdb now. This part of the code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Only something that has a `malloc` (or similar) will need a `free`.

For example, if you struct was like this:

```
struct listNode{
    char *addr;
    struct listNode *next;
};
```

Then you would allocate like this:

```
struct ListNode Node = malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
Node.addr = malloc(size of the string);
```

And you would have to free the string before then freeing the node itself. Your string as part of the struct, with a fixed length and so there is no string to free.

Your issue, however, must be something else. Try to avoid recursion (i.e. your example uses recursion - on a big list this will cause a stack overflow) and nullify your pointers when freeing them, and check pointers (are non null) before using them.

Comment: I guess I should clarify: does calling `free()` on a structure that was returned by `malloc` and that contains a string cause a segmentation error by trying to free the string inside of it?

Comment: No. `free` doesn't know or care about the contents of the block of memory it's releasing.

Comment: Ok sweet thanks for all of the advice. the nodes are allocated exactly like that elsewhere in the code. It seems I will have to continue debugging elsewhere. And as for the recursion, it is a requirement for the project. @AndrewMedico thanks for the answers/comments. now I really understand more about the nature of memory allocation in C. having come to C from Java, this is unfamiliar territory

Comment: If the list gets too big then recursion will be *impossible* - no way around it but to ditch it for a loop!

Comment: there is a command line arg for the program that determines how many times this recurses...and I currently am using 10, so that should not be an issue, but I see how that could hypothetically cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

You probably overran the stack.

Try this:

```
void destroyList(struct listNode *pNode){
    while (pNode) {
        struct listNode *x = pNode;
        pNode = pNode->next;
        free(x);
    }
}
```

Of course it could be you passed in a bad pNode, in which case this won't fix.

Or you have corrupted the heap elsewhere.